# Python TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator

Tags: python, pandas, types, type-conversion, typeerror

I want to create a correlation matrix from scratch. My code below gives an error `TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator`.

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/Admission_Predict.csv')

df = df.sample(frac=1)
mean = df.mean()
cov = {}

for j in range(len(mean)):
    total = 0
    for k in range(len(mean)):

        # Use Pearson correlation for interval variables
        terms = ((df.iloc[i, j] - mean.iloc[j]) * (df.iloc[i, k] - mean.iloc[k]) for i in range(len(mean)))
        covariance = sum(terms) / (len(mean)-1)
        st_dev = statistics.pstdev(df)
        pearson = covariance[j, k] / (st_dev(j) * st_dev(k))

        # If feature k is already in dict, append Pearson. Else, apply feature k as a list object.
        if k in cov:
            cov[k].append(pearson)
        else:
            cov[k] = [pearson]

# Coerce the cov list into a dataframe
cov_df = pd.DataFrame(cov)

# rename the columns of the cov dataframe
col_dict = {}
for idx, col in enumerate(cov_df.columns):
    col_dict[idx] = col
cov_df = cov_df.rename(index=col_dict)

print(cov_df)


> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod2.py", line 17, in
> <module>
>     st_dev = statistics.pstdev(df)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\statistics.py",
> line 813, in pstdev
>     var = pvariance(data, mu)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\statistics.py",
> line 784, in pvariance
>     T, ss = _ss(data, mu)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\statistics.py",
> line 686, in _ss
>     c = mean(data)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\statistics.py",
> line 316, in mean
>     T, total, count = _sum(data)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\statistics.py",
> line 166, in _sum
>     for n, d in map(_exact_ratio, values):   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\statistics.py",
> line 248, in _exact_ratio
>     raise TypeError(msg.format(type(x).__name__)) TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

I attempted to address the error by converting type `str` to numerator/denominator:

```
df_num = list(map(int, df))
st_dev = statistics.pstdev(df_num)
pearson = covariance[j, k] / (st_dev(j) * st_dev(k))
```

However, if gives me a ValueError:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod2.py", line 17, in
> <module>
>     df_num = list(map(int, df)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'GRE Score'
```

Desired output:
I want to emulate the pandas corr() output

```
corr = df.corr()
corr
                   GRE Score  TOEFL Score  ...  Research  Chance of Admit
GRE Score           1.000000     0.835977  ...  0.580391         0.802610
TOEFL Score         0.835977     1.000000  ...  0.489858         0.791594
University Rating   0.668976     0.695590  ...  0.447783         0.711250
SOP                 0.612831     0.657981  ...  0.444029         0.675732
LOR                 0.557555     0.567721  ...  0.396859         0.669889
CGPA                0.833060     0.828417  ...  0.521654         0.873289
Research            0.580391     0.489858  ...  1.000000         0.553202
Chance of Admit     0.802610     0.791594  ...  0.553202         1.000000
```

Comment: @tdelaney I've posted the full traceback.

Comment: I assume you have a column named "GRE Score".

Comment: @tdelaney yes, the first column of the table as shown in df.corr() is `GRE score`.

Comment: Dataframes iterate their column names, not any contained values. If you want to convert the enitre dataframe to int, you could do `df_num = df.astype(int)` to convert the whole thing at once. But the problem may be higher up. `read_csv` tries to guess column data types. If it looks like an integer in the CSV file, it should already be int in the dataframe. You may want to get the dataframe cleaned up right after you read it.

Comment: @tdelaney `df_num = df.astype(int)` returns an error `TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator`.

Comment: Could it be that your csv contains numbers with comas as a fraction instead of decimal point? Or it contains another character encoding than assumed by your program? Also could it be that your target type `int` is too small to store possibly very large numbers of your csv?